# how to use `dependOn` to bundle separate application files from the main entry point?

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules

I have a backend project that I would like to bundle using Webpack v5.

I would like to split some of the files into their own bundles and have them imported into the main entry.

The main entry has a `dependOn` key that contains an array of filenames that will be used by the main entry.

This is the `webpack.config.json`:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: {
      import: './index.ts',
      dependOn: 'routes'
    },
    routes: ['./routes.ts']
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  target: 'node',

  externals: [
    nodeExternals()
  ],

  mode: 'production',

  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ContextReplacementPlugin(/any-promise/)
  ]
};
```

After running the build two files are generated (`app.js` & `routes.js`) as expected. But when running the entry point with NodeJS I get the following error: *****webpack_require**.C*** does not exist.

Going through the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dependencies)  I see that their example `dependOn` is based on packages and not indvidual application files.

Can you add applicaton files to `dependOn`? Does this have something to do with module resolution?

Comment: You are `running the entry point with NodeJS` instead of referencing those two in your HTML page?

Comment: @chenxsan This is bundling two (or more) separate application JS files. The `app.js` references the `routes.js`. There is no HTML page the encapsulates both of these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume you have imported the `routes` in your `app`, and you want to split `routes` into a separate bundle instead of being included in the bundled `app.js`.

Here's how you could make it with SplitChunksPlugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin.

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./index"
    },
    target: "node",
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                routes: {
                    filename: "routes.js",
                    test: module => {
                        return module.resource && module.resource.includes("routes");
                    },
                    enforce: true,
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Webpack will output two files, `app.js` and `routes.js`.